# MySql for the following output

Tags: mysql

I have table as below.
'emp' table contains both employee name in 'name' column and its respected manager id in 'mgr_id' column.If mgr_id column contains value '-' it means he don't have any manager.
If mgr_id=1 then his manager is A,If 2 then B and so on..

```
emp
---
id  name  mgr_id
1    A      -
2    B      1
3    C      1
4    D      2
5    E      3
```

Expected output :

```
emp
---
name  manager
A      -
B      A
C      A
D      B
E      C
```

i need this to be done using mysql query...

Comment: Wha?? We need more about information. I dont have a clue what youre asking

Comment: Looks like homework?

Comment: This is unlikely to help future readers and very confusing

Comment: it was interview ques...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a self-join. Join the same table and use alias names for the tables to distinguish them

```
select e1.name, e2.name as manager
from emp e1
left join emp e2 on e1.mgr_id = e2.id
```